# Number each Partition BY in addition to ROW NUMBER

Tags: sql-server

```
ROW_NUMBER ( )   
OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause )
```

The above code partitions a dataset based on **[value_expressions]** and numbers-off rows within each partition. **How do I add an additional column output that numbers the partitions instead of numbering the rows of each partition?**

Comment: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY <partition by list from RN>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` with the corresponding `OVER` clause. The important part is the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER` clause: put the columns from the `PARTITION BY` of the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the `ORDER BY` in the `DENSE_RANK()`.