# A question for SQL: Row_number returns a unique number in each partition. But is there anyway to give each partition a unique number?

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, row-number

A question for SQL: `Row_number` returns a unique number in each partition of a result set.

But is there any way if I wish to give each partition an unique number?

Comment: Perhaps if you add some sample data and expected result, it would be clearer why the answer isn't just to omit the partition by clause entirely?

Comment: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by x ORDER BY y) as rnum, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER by x) as pnum`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the comment from Martin is doing the trick. Also this question was already addressed here: [Number each Partition BY in addition to ROW NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49261466/number-each-partition-by-in-addition-to-row-number).